How to compare two different HASHES that correspond to a single person
hope y'all doin awesome.
I've been struggling with some HASH stuff, and I've come to a point where I don't really know what to do, so I'm really hoping stackoverflow could give me a hand.
I've depeloped and succesfully deployed my DigitalPersona SDK on my Web App, I'm actually storing user's fingerprints hashes on my DB, but I've reached the point where I try to validate this user hashes with their ones registered (8 per user(4 taken from their index, and 4 from their middle)) I cant really match the one I give from the 'Validation' Form wtih the ones stored.
The Raw Hashes I'm storing varies from 350-to-500 characters per hash, and none of them are really the same, so I can't really make a match or a truthful one per say.
I've tried Jaccard, Hamming, Levensthein, Similarity.js, CosineSimilarity.
And my DB Manager told me he was not going to 'implement' the DBSM.Crypto function because it was too much of a work for him, so I'm stranded here...
All of this methods have been tried and developed on Javascript.
With low faith, I'll wait for any question you have about the code or anything.
Thanks!
Enroll patients and then Validate their Fingerprints, I'm not able to validate  their fingerprints since the raw hash is never the same...

By definition, a secure hash creates a unique result from its input, so comparing one hash to another to see if they're similar or the same does not make any sense.

So how does a fingerprint verification works?
I mean, it takes an input, and 'compares' it with data stored on a DB, finds a match and 'identifies' a person, but... 'by definition, a secure hash creates a unique result from its input', so how does it validates? im so lost.

Hashing probably isn't suitable for something like inexact matching. There's no order with hashes, so you can only find an exact match that way. What you probably want instead is a way of deriving a quantity you can use to represent the distance between two fingerprints. Something like ElasticSearch is for strings. Then you can search for the fingerprints in your DB 'closest' to the one you're testing.
